# StartActivityForResult with MVVM Architecture Components

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

In one of the Google Codelabs, `Activity1` displays a `RecyclerView` and on button click opens `Activity2` where a new entry can be added.

Instead of accessing a `ViewModel` in `Activity2` and adding the entry to the database directly, they send the entry back to `Activity1` and insert it there.

What is the reasoning behind this? Why send the data back to `Activity1`? Why not call `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` in `Activity2` and insert the entry in there?

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewWordActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Word word = new Word(data.getStringExtra(NewWordActivity.EXTRA_REPLY));
        mWordViewModel.insert(word);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Source:
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/MainActivity.java

Comment: post how u sending response from NewWordActivity back like set result or something!

Comment: Because, Google suggests that avoid using Single `ViewModel` due to lifecycle pitfalls to activity, that's why they avoid to use same instance `ViewModel` in second activity & pass data to first activity instead.

Comment: But the second activity could just use the `ViewModelProviders.of` method to get it's own ViewModel instance`

Comment: IMHO, Google has no monopoly on the truth. They make bogus decisions too.

Comment: Because they don't want to create two instances of WordViewModel for two activities. If they use two fragments then yes we can do like what you suggest above, getting the viewModel instance and saving your data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the NewWordActivity class it's very simple and doesn't require its own ViewModel. My guess is that it's to avoid the need to create one for the single purpose of inserting an entry into the database, giving that responsibility to the MainActivity.

Comment: Thank you. Would you still use `startActivityForResult` when there also should be an update feature?

Comment: It wouldn't be necessary if you are using LiveData to observe the database in the first Activity.

Comment: With update I meant updating the entry in the database

Comment: The principle is the same whether you are inserting, updating or deleting entries into your database. Observing with LiveData means that your activity doesn't need to know when to go and check for changes as any changes are automatically propagated to Observers.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to understand if I should still use startActivityForResult then

Comment: What do you expect to be doing when you get a result from an Activity?

Comment: The example in my question sends the data to activity1 and inserts it there

Comment: I mean, that's what this question was about, right?

Comment: Simply calling `ViewModelProviders.of` and `insert` in the 2nd activity would be less work than handling intent extras and activity result, right? So what is the reasoning behind sending the data to the `MainActivity`?

Comment: @FlorianWalther this was exactly my question when I watched your youtube MVVM tutorial. LOL . thanks for the tutorial btw